# XGBoost running twice on terminal and notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science, xgboost

This code for XGBoost runs twice

```
#https://towardsdatascience.com/running-xgboost-on-google-colab-free-gpu-a-case-study-841c90fef101

num_folds = 3
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=num_folds, random_state =seed)
param_grid = {
        'classifier__max_depth': [3],
        'classifier__n_estimators': [200]
    }

gs3 = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv = cv, scoring = 'roc_auc', n_jobs = -1,\
                  verbose = False, return_train_score = True, refit = True)

fit_params={"classifier__early_stopping_rounds": 20, 
            "classifier__eval_metric" : ["error","auc"],
#             "classifier__verbose_eval" : 10,
            "classifier__eval_set" : [[X_train, y_train],[X_test, y_test]]}
            
%time gs3 = gs3.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
print(("best score from grid search: %.3f"
       % gs3.best_score_))
```

First it'll output on terminal
[image]

Then it'll run again on notebook
[image]

Can someone explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out from [this](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training) documentation link. verbose_eval = True by default which causes it to print the logs.

These logs that print after the training are because we've passed parameter for early_stopping_rounds.